# Sending a PUT request to the ZENDESK API to update an organisation via c#

Tags: c#, zendesk-api

I'm getting a 422 error when sending the http rerquest to the zendesk API to update an organisation. The JSON I am sending is valid so not sure where the issue is. I am using the C# http client.

The code:

```
string host = "https://MYZENDESK.zendesk.com";
                    var file = "/api/v2/organizations/" + connectDetails.ToString() + ".json";
                    var details = this.richTextBox1.Text.Replace(@"\",@"\\");
                    var json = "{\"organization\": {\"details\" :\"" + details + "\"}}";
                    Console.Write(json);
                    Console.Read();
                    var jobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);
                    using (var client = new HttpClient())

                    {
                        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |=     SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("authorization", "Basic xxxxxxxxx");
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                        //var response = client.GetAsync(host + file).Result;
                        var response = client.PutAsync(host + file, new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
                        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                            throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
                    }
                }
```

I was hopeing this would work. I can update via postman just fine with the same configuration but there must be some issue with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using RestSharp. Had tried this previously but have found that an older version of RestSharp is needed:

```
using RestSharp;
//use RestSharp v106.1
static void APIcall() {

    var client = new RestClient("https://xxxxx.zendesk.com/api/v2/organizations/xxxxx");
    client.Timeout = -1;
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.PUT);
    request.AddHeader("content", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic xxxxx");
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("Cookie", "_zendesk_cookie=xxxxxx");
    var body = xxxxx
    request.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
APIcall();
```